# Can't launch python3.6 on windows: "Current thread 0x00004d18"

Tags: python, python-3.x

BLUF: Python 3.6 (x86) will NOT execute on Windows

OS: Windows 10E 
x64 Python: 2.7 (working) (c:\python27) 
Python 3.6 (not working) (c:\python36)

I've been running two installs of python for a couple years now, with no issues. Python 2.7 and 3.6, I usually use a python launcher (pywin or winpython) to call either install depending on the program I'm using. never had an issue until today.

So I have no idea what I updated or what software I installed, but I've been working at this for 8 hours, and I can't figure it out.
Python27 launches fine.

Here are the errors:

Error when launching python 3.6 (32Bit) shell:

`Fatal Python error: PyInitialize: unable to load the file system codec File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\init_.py", line 123 raise CodecRegistryError,\ ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Current thread 0x00000a00 (most recent call first):`

Error when launching python 3.6 from a win prompt:

`c:\python36>python.exe Fatal Python error: PyInitialize: unable to load the file system codec File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\init_.py", line 123 raise CodecRegistryError,\ ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Current thread 0x00004e10 (most recent call first):`

So why is it calling Python27’s path? I check the executable for the python3.6 launcher, it's target is c:\python36\python.exe - which is exactly where it's at.

I’ve checked the PATH in EV for both user and system, and it’s good to go.

I've completely ripped out both python2.7 and 3.6 and reinstalled them both but 
I can't get 3.6 to run.

I'm lost

HALP!

Comment: FYI - Installing x64 didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using virtual environments when working with multiple Python versions?

Comment: Yes, however, this should work native.  I've been using the same environment for 2+ years.

Comment: I see that you have Windows 10x64, and you said "Error when launching python 3.6 (32Bit) shell". How about installing Python for x64?

Comment: Great suggestion - What if the python apps are only 32 capable? Also, why would 2.7 run in 32 but not 3.6?